# Linked object for creating chains without lists

Tags: c#, linked-list

I need a `LinkedList` but unfortunatelly the one that the .NET provides didn't have the functionality I was looking for (not working with linq and the LinkedListNode is sealed). I created a *replacement* that works similar but is linq-compatible.

The main class is a `LinkedObject<T>` that might be used on it's own but is better suited to be used by composition and should provide all the functionality of a chain:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Value = {Value?.ToString()}")]
class LinkedObject<T>
{
    private LinkedObject<T> _previous;
    private LinkedObject<T> _next;

    public LinkedObject() {}

    public LinkedObject(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public LinkedObject<T> Previous
    {
        get { return _previous; }
        set
        {
            _previous = value;
            value._next = this;
        }
    }

    public LinkedObject<T> Next
    {
        get { return _next; }
        set
        {
            _next = value;
            value._previous = this;
        }
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }

    // or maybe precessors?
    public IEnumerable<LinkedObject<T>> Before
    {
        get
        {
            var item = this;
            while (item != null)
            {
                yield return item;
                item = item.Previous;
            }
        }
    }

    // or maybe successors?
    public IEnumerable<LinkedObject<T>> After
    {
        get
        {
            var item = this;
            while (item != null)
            {
                yield return item;
                item = item.Next;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Remove()
    {            
        _previous.Next = _next;
        _next.Previous = _previous;
        _previous = null;
        _next = null;
    }
}
```

Some custom object would use it like this *(my real linked-object has a few more additional properties then this simple example)*:

```
class Word
{
    private readonly LinkedObject<Sentence> _linkedObject;

    public Word()
    {
        _linkedObject = new LinkedObject<Sentence>(this);
    }

    public string Value 
    { 
        get { return _linkedObject.Value; } 
        set { _linkedObject.Value = value; }
    }        

    public WordPrevious
    {
        get { return _linkedObject.Previous.Value; }
        set { _linkedObject.Previous = value._linkedObject; }
    }

    public Word Next
    {
        get { return _linkedObject.Next.Value; }
        set { _linkedObject.Next = value._linkedObject; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Word> Before
    {
        get { return _linkedObject.Before.Select(x => x.Value); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Word> After
    {
        get { return _linkedObject.After.Select(x => x.Value); }
    }
}
```

Example (I use a loop to create the real chain):

```
var foo = new LinkedObject<string>
{
    Value = "foo",
    Next = new LinkedObject<string>
    {
        Value = "bar",
        Next = new LinkedObject<string>() { Value = "baz" }
    }
};

// foo, bar, baz

foo.Next.Remove(); // foo, baz
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, which parts of LINQ aren't working for you with the .NET built-in `LinkedList`?   Everything I'm testing in VS2015 is working for me.

Comment: @BenC it's returning the actual values instead of `LinkedListNode` so after you've got something with `Where` etc. you're left without the possibility to use `Next` or `Previous`... you'd need to do another search with the `Find` method to get the `LinkedListNode` again.

Comment: Another example how you can use it with linq `word.After.Last().Next = new Word()` or any other place. You can add/insert items where ever you want by only acting on the items themself that build the actuall list instead of being held by such.

Comment: Why can't you use the `List` specific methods in first place? Sounds a reasonable trade for me.

Comment: @BrunoCosta I cannot use it becasue it requires the object it stores and I need to find elements by various properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule your own `Find` extension method instead of redoing it all over again.

```
public static LinkedListNode<T> Find<T>(this LinkedList<T> list, Predicate<T> pred)
{
    var node = list.First;
    while (node != null)
    {
        if (pred(node.Value))
        {
            return node;
        }
        node = node.Next;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Oh, was this simple ;-) I guess I have to rethink my idea...